# not returning the correct row in criteria yii

Tags: php, yii

I keep getting the first record. Yes I know I wrote `$model[0]` but why didn't it use the function to get the first record found given the product id? It seems like no matter what's in the parameters, it just returns the first record.

controller:

```
foreach ($basket as $item){     
    if($item->product->store_id==$value){
    //here... tried hard coding different things in the params.. doesn't work
    $shipping = table::model()->getProductShipRate(322, $from, $to);        
    $ship_fee = $shipping[0]->ships_to_fee;
    //blah blah
    print_r($shipping[0]->add_cost); // always give me the first entry.
    }
   }
```

model:

```
public function getProductShipRate($pid,$from,$to){ //doesn't do anthing dont know why.
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->condition='product_id="'.$pid.'"';
            $criteria->condition='ships_from="'.$from.'"';
            $criteria->condition='ships_to="'.$to.'"';      
            $record =$this->findAll($criteria);

            if(!empty($record))
                return $record;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is here:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition='product_id="'.$pid.'"';
$criteria->condition='ships_from="'.$from.'"';
$criteria->condition='ships_to="'.$to.'"';
```

You replaced condition with next string. Use this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('product_id="'.$pid.'"');
$criteria->addCondition('ships_from="'.$from.'"');
$criteria->addCondition('ships_to="'.$to.'"');
```

But better look this:

```
public function getProductShipRate($pid,$from,$to){
    return $this->findAll(
                'product_id = :pid AND ships_from = :from AND ships_to = :to'
                ['pid' => $pid, 'from' => $from, 'to' => $to]
    );
}
```

Comment: +1 for for using params.. or you could use 
$criteria->params = array();